# Count the number of digits of a floating-point number

Tags: c, performance, math, floating-point, digits

Is there any efficient way (without converting the float into a string) to obtain the number of digits a floating-point number consists of (independent of its length and precision) ?

---

On that way I can implement a fairly good, portable, problematic-less function for comparison/conditioning by multiplying the float by the number of the digits it consists of.

Comment: Do you mean like 1.2 has 2, and 1.21 has 3? Where basically the digits end where a 0 begin or when precision is hit ?

Comment: What would the length of PI be?

Comment: Since `0.1` in code is not precisely the mathematical number `0.1`, what is your expected number of digits of it? Your thought *is* problematic, making the question unclear.

Comment: I slightly disagree but mostly agree. Most IEEE FP numbers will all have the same number of digits and in no significant way.

Comment: `0.53` has three digits, `0.1` has two digits, `0.4444` has 5 digits. `0.53 * 100 = 53`, `0.1 * 10 = 10`, `0.4444 * 1000 = 4444`

Comment: @ydobonebi so yes you are right. Take it literally.. my question is not unclear. In fact, it cannot be any clearer.

Comment: What about `0.1000000000000003`? Because that's what you might get if you tried to print out `0.1` as a `double`.

Comment: Again, in code, `0.1 * 10 == 10` is false, so your thought is not practical.

Comment: @Malina Sorry, I tend to be a bit passive. My point is you really can't because what you get isn't what you got. If you say float x = 1.01 you would expect to get 3 back from your question's answer. However as has been pointed out, that may actually be stored as 1.0100000001 which would actually be 10.....effectively the same number, but different results.

Comment: @Malina: Your question is clear.  It just doesn't make any sense.  You may as well ask how many digits there are in a hamburger or why so many cattle had to be slaughtered to make your `double`.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch π, being a transcendental number, has an infinite number of decimal digits.  Machine PI, like `M_PI` may have an exact  `double` value like `3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875` or 49 digits. Agree with your comment's implication that knowing the "length" of pi or any FP is not that useful.

Comment: `1,00001 * 100000 = 100001` `1,00010 * 100000 = 100010` `100001 < 100010` so the comparison is true

Comment: @Malina `1.00001` is rarely _exactly_ representable as a `double`.  Instead `1,00001 * 100000 = 100001` is done in typical C as `1.000010000000000065512040237081237137317657470703125 * 100000` and the product is rounded to the closest `double`: the result is `100001`.  Should you experiment with other such multiplications, you will likely come across one that does not equal the expected result due to 1) binary implementation of FP numbers and 2) rounding of the product.

Comment: Applying this idea it should be 1.000010000000000065512040237081237137317657470703125 * 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: @Malina Unclear in your comment why multiplying `1.000010...125` by zero?  Did you mean `... * 1e50`?

Comment: @chux I forgot to add the `1` at the beginning. I made it worse, because of that, but I had to leave PC urgently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q: Is there any efficient way to obtain the number of digits a floating-point number?
A: I doubt it.

Every finite FP number is *exact*, but maybe not the exact value one thinks.

Due to typical [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) implementation of a `double`,
`double x = 0.53`, `x` value: `.5300000000000000266453525910037569701671600341796875`, 52 digits.
`double x = 0.1`, `x` value:`.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625` 55 digits.
The next closest `double` to mathematical `0.1` is `.09999999999999999167332731531132594682276248931884765625` with 56 digits.

`DBL_MAX`: in decimal, typically about 300 digits `17976931348623158...` ending with `6728515625.`.

`DBL_MIN`: typically   `0.000000(~300 zeros) 22250738585072014... (maybe about 700 more digits)`.

Comparison of FP numbers need not determine the number of digitis in its decimal representation.  To compare FP  numbers, use the usual relationship operators `>, >=, ==`, etc.

Theses values are illustrative.  YMMV.

Comment: The problem with my idea is that `12,5 * 100 = 1250` which would also be the result of `0,125 * 1000 = 1250`

Comment: Malina Certainly you can find _select_ numbers that have simple _exact_ decimal representation like 12.5, but not 0.53 nor 0.1.  You will quickly have trouble with FP numbers in general. As @ydobonebi commented, most FP numbers have many decimal digits when printed exactly.  Of course code can round to say 5 or 6 digits, but then code begins only have approximate answers.  The question comes down to how much inaccuracy can you tolerate and what is the real problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: converting the floating point number into a corresponding integral number.

Comment: @Malina How do you propose converting 1/3 to an integral number?  What about this answer's examples?  Why do you want to convert decimals to integers, and what do you want to do with those integers?

Comment: @Teepeemm I suspect your above comment was for OP and not me.  If so, suggest moving to the question section or prepending @ Malina to the comment here.